# JS loaded content (Yandex Map) and android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, yandex-api, yandex-maps

I'm making a web application, using webview. On one of the pages of the site that is used in the application there is a built-in Yandex map.
On devices with Android 4 and below, the map is not displayed. I found out that the event "ymaps.ready", in which the "init" function is passed, which creates an instance of the map, does not work. If you call the "init" function with a timeout, that caused the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in the line

```
myMap = new ymaps.Map
```

As I understand, the application does not see the ymaps object, although the Yandex library is loaded. I tried to load the Yandex library from my server - the same result. All the necessary permissions in the application are exposed. setJavaScriptEnabled = true. In android 6 and above, the maps are displayed. What can be wrong?
Thanks! And sorry for my english.

The code is below:

```
var myMap;
ymaps.ready(init);
setTimeout(init, 5000);
function init () {
    alert('init');
    // Creation of a map instance and its binding to a container with id 'map'
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    document.getElementById('destroyButton').onclick = function () {
        myMap.destroy();
    };

}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Примеры. Размещение карты на странице.</title>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<input type="button" id="destroyButton" value="Удалить карту"/>
</body>

</html>

package com.androidmkab.webview;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Date;
        import android.Manifest;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.os.Parcelable;
        import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
        import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
        import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
        import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
        import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
        import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );
        return imageFile;
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
        //Get webview
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        // Define url that will open in webview
        String webViewUrl = "http://test3.kaz-press.kz/";
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        // Other webview options
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //Other webview settings
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);
        // Define Webview manage classes
        startWebView();

    }


    private void startWebView() {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if(url.contains("google")){
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

        });


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }


            // For Android 5.0
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePath;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        //Log.e(Common.TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Выбор изображения");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                return true;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){

                // Update message
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                try{
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    File imageStorageDir = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                            , "QualityControl");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }
                    // Create camera captured image file path and name
                    File file = new File(
                            imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    + ".jpg");
                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    // Camera capture image intent
                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    // Create file chooser intent
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Выбор изображения");

                    // Set camera intent to file chooser
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                            , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                    // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                        String acceptType,
                                        String capture) {

                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

            // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
            // console message informing what action to perform,
            // taking a photo or updating the file

            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging 1: " + cm);
                onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message+" "+lineNumber+" "+sourceID);

            }
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
            }
        });   // End setWebChromeClient

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
            return;
        } else {
            if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {

                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;

                }

                Uri result=null;

                try{
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                        result = null;

                    } else {

                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;

            }
        }
    }
    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack()) {

            webView.goBack();

        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidmkab.webview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is this the same with 2.1.oldie.1 version instead of 2.1? Looks like the issue is caused by old web browser in webView.

Comment: Thanks! It works with 2.1.oldie.1 version

Comment: Good, but pay attention that this version won't have any updates - it's for deprecated browsers and has no recent features.